# How to get value area high and low (as in session (daily/weekly/etc.) volume profile) of the previous day plotted as levels?

Tags: pine-script

How to get value area high and low (as in session (daily/weekly/etc.) volume profile) of the previous day plotted as levels? Manually plotted VAH and VAL as orange lines shown in the picture below:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below are some scripts that should assist you with your coding.
Within the settings you can change the timeframe to daily weekly etc to plot those value areas.

Hancock - POC VA
https://uk.tradingview.com/script/xGRsUBqr-Hancock-POC-VA/

POCs and VAHs VALs - All and Non-Broken
https://uk.tradingview.com/script/xiCqpipd-POCs-and-VAHs-VALs-All-and-Non-Broken/

I would also take note that the built in TV Volume Profile is not pinescript. I think I read somewhere but can't find the link that its java.

So by producing an indicator it will not give you the exact same results. As the volume profile is subject to what value area you use, the timeframe you are on and row size selected. So you could have it on row size 500, value area 70% and on 1 hour timeframe you will get a slightly different result to the 5 min timeframe.

Comment: Thanks for a reply! I do use Hancock but It has that issue where it's not really stable/usable for daily lines if you use higher timeframe than 1min. Definitely going to check your other link. But I do have a feeling that this problem might be unsolvable as it really feels like in-built volume profile is non pine stuff and that's probably for a reason...

Comment: Plot several volume profiles using the built in TV indicator change row size to 500. Then change time frames. You see that the VAH/VAL and POC changes. If you then read this link https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000502040-volume-profile/ it explains why this happens under Chart resolution Resolution of bars used for VP calculation. What are you aiming to achieve with the indicator as you would just place an order on an plotted line you would ladder either side for SFP etc.

Comment: Have you got any further with this, I am keen to follow and understand your findings/research.

Comment: Didn't have much time, but gonna let you know If I solve my issues.